# FileStream Acces Denied

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

I currently have a problem with a C# program. I tried to do a filestream to create or edit a file and I can't seem to make it work.

I permanently have an exception "Access Denied" but I tried everything (give rights to all users, run as administrator, syntax)

To be honest I'm a little lost ...

I even tried to take a sample from a tutorial to be sure that I don't have any syntax problem but no.

```
public MainPage()
{
  this.InitializeComponent();
  string dir = @"C:\temp\data.bin";

  FileStream fs = new FileStream(dir, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
  fs.Close();
}
```

Even with the default Visual Studio folder it doesn't work :

```
string dir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
string fil = @"\data.bin";

FileStream fs = new FileStream(dir + fil, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
fs.Close();
```

This code give me the exception :

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException : 'Access to the path 'C:\Users\Arthok\source\repos\test\test\bin\x64\Debug\AppX\data.bin' is denied.'

EDIT : Going to try with the UWP locations #pm100

Comment: IS the file already open, or locked?

Comment: The problem seems to be that you're targeting "uwp". Windows 10 tablet programs cannot access most of the filesystem, even if you've got the right permissions.

Comment: @Alejandro It can be that yeah .. Do you know where I should try ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions

Comment: Are you use vs studio in administer mode ?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks all but I was just in UWP and didn't realize that FileStream wouldn't work.
So the answer was obviously in the manual (thanks to pm100):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-reading-and-writing-files

And I just had to create the file with this command :

```
Windows.Storage.StorageFolder storageFolder =
Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
Windows.Storage.StorageFile sampleFile =
await storageFolder.CreateFileAsync("sample.txt", Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `FileMode.OpenOrCreate`. Also try running you application with elevated privilege.

Comment: This is UWP, UWP has very restricted privileges and can't write in arbitrary folders. revise the link from pm100: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions